# Azure Pipline Deploy to Kubernetes: Override image reference

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have an deployment.yml file with one container, something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
[...]
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: acr/my-app:1.0 #-> should be completly overridden!
```

and an Azure DevOps job that does a dock build/push and should than deploy my app:

```
variables:
  imageRepository: 'my-app'
  containerRegistry: 'acr'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myapp/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

[...]

- task: KubernetesManifest@0
      displayName: Deploy on kubernetes cluster
      inputs:
        action: 'deploy'
        kubernetesServiceConnection: '...'
        namespace: 'default'
        manifests: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment.yml'
        containers: |
          $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

I want the complete image reference value in the deployment.yml to be overridden. But I don't get how to write a working placeholder. I tried many different things, from `$(VALUE)` over `VALUE` to ``{{ VALUE }} ,e.g:

`image: ${{ variables.containerRegistry }} / ${{ variables.imageRepository }} : ${{ variables.tag}}`. But the placeholder is not replaced at all and the pod fails with invalid image refernece.

Can Azure DevOps do this or do I need to override the image value via bash task or something like this?

**Update**

To clarify my requirements:
I want to override the complete string, since I want to reuse the file for multiple stages, where only the registry  the tag are difficult. E.g.: `acr1/my-app:tag1` and `acr2/my-app:tag2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops

```
The fully qualified URL of the image to be used for substitutions on the manifest files. This input accepts the specification of multiple artifact substitutions in newline-separated form. Here's an example:

containers: |
  contosodemo.azurecr.io/foo:test1
  contosodemo.azurecr.io/bar:test2

In this example, all references to contosodemo.azurecr.io/foo and contosodemo.azurecr.io/bar are searched for in the image field of the input manifest files. For each match found, the tag test1 or test2 replaces the matched reference.
```

You will need to ensure that the string in your manifest matches the registry/image:tag string in your KubernetesManifestTask

Azure DevOps fill wine the matching registry/image and update the tag portion

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but it only works, if I have the ``image: registry/image:tag`` in the yml. But I want to override the complete string, since I want to reuse the file for multiple stages, where only the registry  the tag are difficult. E.g.: ``acr1/my-app:tag1`` and ``acr2/my-app:tag2``

Comment: in that case, you will need to bake your manifest with kustomize or helm2 and use the Bake Action
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops#bake-action
this will allow you to templatize your manifest and change the image before passing the manifest to the KubernetesManifest Task

Comment: OK, I was hoping I can bypass this extra step. Thanks anyway!